# MySQL query to select number of fields occurring more times than x

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

I want to find out the 'rank' of a word in any given language. A word with a rank of `1` means it's the most commonly used word in the language.

There are two MySQL tables.

#### document:

- id: 1
- language: "english"

#### word:

- id: 2
- body: "the"
- document_id: 1

There are about 1 million rows in the `word` table. Here is a query that works, but it takes 7-10 seconds. Is there a better way to write this query?

```
select count(*) + 1
    from (
        select word.body, count(*) as count
        from word
        join document on word.document_id = document.id
        where document.language = 'english'
        group by word.body
    ) t
    where count > (select count
    from (
        select word.body, count(*) as count
        from word
        join document on word.document_id = document.id
        where document.language = 'english'
        group by word.body
    ) t
    where body = 'the')
```

Comment: Are you sure that is a problem you want to solve with SQL? I'd have used full-text indexing for that which usually implies using extensions such as Sphinx.

Comment: I'm open to alternative solutions.

Comment: What types of indexes exist on the word table? _This_ mentioned FT's, which might be a good place to start...

Comment: I have an index on word.document_id and word.body. It helped with other queries. I put a fulltext index on document.body(not listed in question), but I was unable to query document.body to get the desired result. (And other fulltext queries were slower , too)

Comment: Hmm... how often is data updated in the `word` table? And how often is the query above run? Perhaps some caching/memoization technique might help...

Answer (score 1):

Initially I was thinking of suggesting the `HAVING` clause, but I don't think that would help in this case, since the query selects the aggregated count and uses that for a comparison.

One option is to use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) but apparently those aren't introduced until MySQL version 8. One other option is to make a [View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-syntax.html):

```
CREATE VIEW countEnglishWord as select word.body, count(*) as count
    from word
    join document on word.document_id = document.id
    where document.language = 'english'
    group by word.body;
```

and use it like this:

```
select count(*) + 1, body
from countEnglishWord c
where count > (select count
  from countEnglishWord t
  where body = 'the'
)
```

I haven't tested it on a million rows... but 3 in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97c702/4).

Comment: This works, but doesn't affect performance.